# Login to Magento 2. from outside, with Guzzle, returns a invalid form_key

Tags: magento2, login, form-key

I'm trying to login to Magento 2, with a form which contains a "from_key". I scrape this form_key but I'm not able to successfully login. Has someone any idea how to make this work? This is my code:

```
        $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
        $jar = new \GuzzleHttp\Cookie\CookieJar();
        $request = $client->request('GET', 'https://www.waiglobal.com/eu_nl/customer/account/login/', [
            'cookies' => $jar,
        ]);

        $content = $request->getBody()->getContents();
        $html = str_get_html($content);

        foreach($html->find('input[name=form_key]') as $rows) {
            $form_key = $rows->value;
        }
        
        $request = $client->request('POST', 'https://www.waiglobal.com/eu_nl/customer/account/login/', [
            "form_params" => [
                "form_key" => $form_key,
                "login[username]" => "username",
                "login[password]" => "password",
            ],
            'cookies' => $jar,
        ]);
        return $jar;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the post URL for:

https://www.waiglobal.com/eu_nl/customer/account/loginPost/

It must be enough.

Comment: Thanks! I tried it, and it still returns "invalid form key" through out the header.